Client timeout connection in MySQL
I'm trying to limit the amount of time my MariaDB client will wait when trying to open a connection to the server.  All my searches instead find only server-side limitations for timing out stale/inactive connections, nothing client-side.
/etc/ssh/ssh_config, for example, has:
ConnectTimeout
  Specifies the timeout (in seconds) used when connecting to the
  SSH server, instead of using the default system TCP timeout.

If I try to use mysqlshow for example:
# time mysqlshow && echo success || echo fail
mysqlshow: Can't connect to server on 'sql.example.edu' (60)

real    1m15.012s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.007s
fail

If the client can't connect, I'd like it to timeout sooner than 75 seconds.  Is there a knob to control this?
Update 1
--connect_timeout=N doesn't seem to change anything:
# time mariadb-show --connect_timeout=10
mariadb-show: unknown variable 'connect_timeout=10'

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.008s
# time mariadb --connect_timeout=10
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'sql.example.edu' (60)

real    1m15.017s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.014s

Thank you!

Have you looked at connect_timeout and net_retry_count? It appears from the source code that both are used by the client.

@mustaccio My apologies, I should have tagged this as mariadb, not mysql. Edited and updated.
